# msiexec can't read path in parent directory

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-installer

I'm trying to install a .msi package (adobe reader) through Microsoft msiexec
I wan't to do a silent install
my Code Looks like this:

    `msiexec /a "%~dp0..\adobe\setup"`

problem:
whenever I use double dot (..) in msiexec command path I get an error

    `msiexec /a "adobe\setup"`

works fine.

so, I even couldn't find a single example using similar path in msiexec command.
any help would be appreciated.
without msiexec none /S /qn or /silent works
So I'm out of ideas.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `cd..` before you run the file?

Comment: thank you!  I'm such a stupid.

Comment: Haha I'm sure your not :) I'll try to think of a better way though...

Comment: If there is an error message, please paste it into the question. Are you sure that the current working directory is relative to ..\adobe? You might try specifying the extension .msi explicitly.'

Comment: no everything is correct. I try i:\adobe\setup works BUT I need i:\x64\..\adobe\setup , because I run script in x64, so dp0 is i:\x64 hence, I need to go back to parent directory with .. and run adobe\setup, so CD did the trick. thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 2 options, either:

```
cd..
msiexec adobe\setup.msi
```

Or

```
set parent=%~dp0
msiexec %parent%adobe\setup.msi
```